# WCF Client connecting to RESTful service is not working

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to use svcutil generated client to communicate with a RESTful WCF service.

The service contract is defined as:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetTest?a={a}&b={b}&c={c}")]
    int GetTest(int a, int b, int c);
}
```

I used Visual Studio to reference this service and used the generated client code to invoke the GetTest operation. Unfortunately, I got this message:

```
Operation 'GetTest' of contract 'IService1' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapperelements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped
```

But when I requested the corresponding URL from web browser, it worked and correct return value was shown.

This is weird. Is there anything wrong with the generated client code? Or did I mis-configured anything?

The following is my client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Service1EndPointBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8010/Service1/" behaviorConfiguration="Service1EndPointBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
            name="Service1EndPoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your method

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Explanation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle.aspx